# Hide top admin menu

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, system.xml

How to hide top menu and disable my custom module, if field "enabled" is 0(no). Magento version 1.9

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <plumrocket translate="title">
        <label>Plumrocket</label>
        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    </plumrocket>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <productlabels translate="title">
        <label>Product Labels</label>
        <tab>plumrocket</tab>
        <backend_model>productlabels/system</backend_model>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <global>
                <label translate="title">Settings</label>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <enabled>
                        <label translate="title">Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </enabled>
                </fields>
            </global>
        </groups>
    </productlabels>
</sections>
```

Comment: Why you don't disable the module from xml file under app/etc/modules? it will remove every configurations from the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `etc/adminhtml.xml`, in which you define your top menu item, you can use the `<depends></depends>` node in the same way as you would do in `system.xml` to make one option depend on another one.

This means, in your `etc/adminhtml.xml` you can do something like this (note: you need to adapt `vendor_module` by yourself as it is not declared in your question):

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <vendor_module module="vendor_module">
            <depends>
                <config>productlabels/global/enabled</config> <!-- as defined in your system.xml -->
            </depends>
            <title>Vendor Module Title</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <action>vendor_module/adminhtml_something</action>
        </vendor_module>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

The magic part in this is the `<depends><config>productlabels/global/enabled</config></depends>` which makes Magento check for whether this option is set to `Yes` or `No` in System -> Configuration -> Your Module -> Your Option.

Important note: This **does not mean** that your controller action **is not** reachable! If you want to hinder the user to reach the page behind by entering its direct URL you'll have to cover this separately.

Comment: Thank you, it working but section in top menu make hidden when i  am refrashe cache. I try clean cache on event "admin_system_config_changed_section_productlabels" but i dont know how do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, @ПетроЧайківський, I think I can not follow. You mean you set the visibility flag to "no" but the menu item is still visible until you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the top menu, it's configuration settings, but you can hide them by commenting on the `<tab> ... </ tab>` tag. 
Then the Magento will not know which module these settings belong to. 
The top menu settings are in the `<menu>`

Comment: it menu in System>Configuration, there is field "enabled", when endbled equal 0 i need hide the one section from top menu

Comment: you need to use jQuery, hide the field, if at change (), value = 0.

Comment: bad idea and i dont know how to use jQuery in Magento

Comment: write jquery in the template  that connects to the page. jQuery is already connected

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko - jQuery as such is interpreted in the browser, hence you would need to view the modules settings page in order to be able to hide a top menu item. Any other page would show the menu item anyway, since you can not refer to something that is not present in the html output in this way.